# image handling in laravel

Tags: php, image, laravel, laravel-4

```
(HTML::image('assets/uploads/design/'.$row->DesignImage,'photo', array( 'width' => 80, 'height' => 80, 'onerror' =>'"this.src="404.png' ) ))
```

Here i need to handle the error image

so i am using

```
<img src="real.png" onerror="this.src='404.png'" />
```

So i need to give the `onerror="this.src='404.png'"`

I need to give the 404.png in the single quote

How can i do this in the laravel way in this place

```
 'onerror' =>'"this.src="404.png' )
```

I am getting output in double quote, How can i give single quote to the 404.png path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have formatted my answer for readability. You can escape the single quotes inside using the backslashes.

```
HTML::image('assets/uploads/design/' . $row->DesignImage, 'photo',
    array(
        'width' => 80,
        'height' => 80,
        'onerror' =>'this.src=\'404.png\''
    )
)
```

Also note the position of the single quotes (which were placed incorrectly in your original question).

Comment: Thanks, i was missing in the escaping